# Bubble Sort of book titles

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

I need to make C++ code of sorting of book titles:

1. display the book titles.
2. display the book title in alphabetical order.

I was able to do the first but I'm having difficulties in displaying the alphabetical order of books.

Here's my code:

```
#include"stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <map>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

const int MAX = 5;

void BubbleSort(string books, int max);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string books[MAX];

    //inputs
    std::cout << "Enter Book titles: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Book [" << i << "]: ";
        //cin >> books[i];
        getline(std::cin, books[i]);

    }
    // print the titles stored in books[i] variable
    cout << "Book Titles Entered \n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Book No." << i << ": ";
        cout << books[i] << endl;

    }

    // print the titles after sort
    cout << "Book Titles In Sort Ascending \n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
        cout << books[i] << "\n";

}

void BubbleSort(string books, int size)
{
    int result;
    for (int pass = 0; pass < size - 1; ++pass)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX - 1 - pass; ++i)
        {
            result = string (books[i], books[i + 1]);
            if (result > 0) {
                swap(books[i], books[i + 1]);
            }
        }
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: what string compare is that supposed to be: `result = string (books[i], books[i + 1]);`?

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling `BubbleSort`.

On the other hand, except this is a homework or similar and *you have to implement Bubble Sort*, I'd recommend you to use `std::sort`. In addition, replace the static array with a dynamic array such as `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::string> books;
// <input here>: use books.push_back to insert new strings
std::sort(books.begin(), books.end());
```

If you know the number of books in advance you can pre-allocate the memory reducing the complexity of insertions: `books.reserve(MAX)`.

Comment: Or use ```std::array```